# How to change currentTime format with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to display the current time and the duration of my videos on my website in this format 00:00. But I don't get it...

```
myVideo.on('timeupdate', function() {
    $('.current').text(myVideo[0].currentTime);
    $('.duration').text(myVideo[0].duration);
});
```

I have found this function, but if I'm honest, I have completely no idea about how to implement it to the currentTime and duration properties...

```
var formatTime = function(seconds) {
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
        seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
        seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        return minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
```

http://gyazo.com/351cafacbeacddbeda7f31869269376e

**EDITED**

Ok... I only had to do this... Hope this helps... haha

```
var formatTime = function(seconds) {
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
    seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

myVideo.on('timeupdate', function() {
    $('.current').text(formatTime(myVideo[0].currentTime));
    $('.duration').text(formatTime(myVideo[0].duration));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) 
it is a library dedicated for handling date

In Datejs library, there is a method "format(str)" where str is the target format 
or you can user "toString(str)" which also takes the target format

[image]

Check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) for more info